# How to change user name

Tags: terminal, users, rename, application, useradd

I somehow changed my prompt (`PS1`) from `[mpatil@localhost ~]$` to `bash-4.1$`. I also have changed my user `mpatil`'s home directory from `/home/mpatil` to `/home/algo`. Now some applications are not working correctly, and I get this error when opening some application:

[image]

How can I change the prompt to what it was before, and how can I get the application to work again?

Comment: I meant we could continue the discussion here. Your command works now, because it doesn't output anything: `touch` is not supposed to print anything when it created the file succesfully. Does the program about which you have the screenshot on your question work now?

Comment: What does your prompt look now?

Comment: it looking [mpatil@localhost ~]$

Comment: Okay, so everything is now working. Good.

Comment: @Risto ya working

Comment: i already accepted

Comment: @Risto ya you are right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is due to you renamed your user's (`mpatil`) home directory to `/home/algo`. That causes that some applications can't read their configurations, because you don't have the directory `/home/mpatil` anymore. The problem will be solved, when you rename the directory `/home/algo` to `/home/mpatil`. You can do that with the following command: `mv /home/algo /home/mpatil`.

Comment: What do you mean by "suggest me"?

Comment: sorry for that.i mean I have one doubt can you clarify that

Comment: What should I clarify?

Comment: in download folder i have one file that is  /home/mpatil/Desktop/Ram/downloads/yoono-desktop-1.8.43.tar.bz2.when i try to install this file am getting error,there is no such file or directory.But when i try to open this file,first folder name is "." then yoono-desktop is there.why like this?

Comment: You really should make it as an separate question. Then I could try to help you. And that because it is how Stack Exchange works: don't do follow-up questions, instead ask a different question.

Comment: ok wait i'will post another question.i hope u will answer

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems here and I'm not sure they are linked together.

1. You need to setup your bash prompt if you want it looked like this `[mpatil@localhost ~]$`. Here is a way to do this : [How to setup custom bash prompt](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-linux-unix-bash-shell-setup-prompt.html)
2. Does the file `/home/mpatil/.sqldevelopper` exist ? If so, what is written in it ?

Comment: /home/mpatil/.sqldevelopper ya exist

Comment: how to change bash-4.1$ - [mpatil@localhost ~]$.? previously  when i open terminal  [mpatil@localhost ~]$ showing.now it showing bash-4.1$.now i cant open application .

Comment: all applications are in /home/mpatil and now am in currently /home/algo.

Comment: @Risto present aam in home/algo directory.how to go to /home/mpatil ?

Comment: only mpatil....

Comment: @Risto ya ya u are right

Comment: how to go /home/mpatil..?

Comment: previously /home/mpatil/ just i renamed to /home/algo.now no application doesnt open

Comment: So you renamed `/home/mpatil/` to `/home/algo/`? The error message comes, because the program tries to read file from `/home/mpatil/`, which doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: I don't know how i changed.now my total system in /home/algo. How to go to from /home/algo/ to /home/mpatil/

Comment: SQL developer is in /home/mpatil but now am in /home/algo

Comment: bash-4.1$ cd /home/mpatil/
bash: cd: /home/mpatil/: No such file or directory

Comment: That says very clearly: you don't have `/home/mpatil` anymore, because you renamed it to `/home/algo`. It means that all your files are in `/home/algo`. The error message comes from, as I have said before many times, that the program tries to read file which is not existent. You have to change the program somehow to read the configuration from `/home/algo`.

Comment: You have to change the program somehow to read the configuration from /home/algo?

Comment: when i tried in terminal `bash-4.1$ whoami` it showing 
`mpatil`

Comment: all my programs are installed in root folder

Comment: that is [root@mpatil ~]#

Comment: when i tried to create on a destop it showing error like Error stating file '/home/mpatil/Desktop': No such file or directory.why?

Comment: @ram I've said this to you already, many times: your errors are due to this: your username is `mpatil`, and it's home directory is by default `/home/mpatil/`, but you renamed it's home directory, so it's now `/home/algo/`. When you try to create file to `/home/mpatil/Desktop`, it shows an error, because you don't have directory called that. Your all problems should be solved when you rename the directory `/home/algo/` to `/home/mpatil`.

Comment: now what to do tell me, to solve this problem ?

Comment: Write this to terminal: `mv /home/algo /home/mpatil`. After you've done that, try for example create the file `/home/mpatil/hello` and then tell me if it's succesful.

Comment: `[root@localhost /]# mv /home/algo /home/mpatil
[root@localhost /]# `

Comment: `[root@localhost /]# /home/mpatil/hello
bash: /home/mpatil/hello: No such file or directory`

Comment: You cannot create file like that. This is the right way to create file: `touch /home/mpatil/hello`

Comment: its not successfully created

Comment: As I said, try this: `touch /home/mpatil/hello`

Comment: @ram Could we continue this discussion under your question?

Comment: [root@localhost /]# touch /home/mpatil/hello
[root@localhost /]# nothing will comming

Comment: ya we will continue this discussion

Comment: @Risto Salminen  are you there?

Comment: now all things have and now i am all things thanq for helping thnaq

Comment: all prgrms have but all are in tr.bz forms.it means again will install these programs?

Comment: i restarted my machine.now all things works fine thank you for helping :).Am happy with your answers

Comment: I will make this as an answer so others will now your problem is solved. I also edited your question to be more clear.

Comment: @pieside Sorry about our discussion here.

Comment: @Richard ya clear